# Firebase Auth with Email and password with saved Email on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase with my android app and I am facing the following problem: If I try to log in to my app with Email, which is in android accounts it's not logging in and there's no error message.

I tried many things like:

- Enable Anonymous logging in firebase
- clean Project

but I still don't Understand why that happened with only saved Email to Phone

And Here is my Code

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(themail, thepass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                mDatabase.child(MyStrings.MISTER_NODE)
                                        .child(user.getUid())
                                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                                        new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() !=null)
                                                {
                                                    UiMister ui = dataSnapshot.getValue(UiMister.class);
                                                    Log.e("uioew",dataSnapshot.toString());
                                                   //


                                                    progressDialog.cancel();
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    finish();

                                                }}

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        }
                                );
```

Comment: could you please add your code

Comment: Have you tried logging out the databaseError in onCancelled?

Comment: yes and No erro 
and If I try to log in with any another account it`s works